# Dashboard Menu settings

Tags: dashboard

How can I get `Pages` and `All Pages` ??  My code outputs `Pages` and `Pages`. My code is like below

```
add_menu_page( 'Pages', 'Pages', 'manage_options', 'Pages', 'page_callback_function', 'dashicons-media-spreadsheet', 26 );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_menu_page');
function custom_menu_page(){
add_menu_page( 'Pages', 'Pages', 'manage_options', 'Pages', 'page_callback_function', 'dashicons-media-spreadsheet', 26 );
add_submenu_page( 'Pages', 'All Pages', 'All Pages', 'manage_options', 'all-pages-list', 'subpage_callback_function' ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhupen for your solution. Your solution produces `Pages` at top and `All Pages` at bottom. But I need `All Pages` at top and `Add New` at bottom and `Pages` in left side. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX4HD.png. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
function admin_pages_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'Pages', 'Pages', 'manage_options', 'pages', 'page_callback_function', 'dashicons-media-spreadsheet', 26 );
    add_submenu_page( 'pages', 'All Pages', 'All Pages', 'manage_options', 'all-pages-list', 'subpage_callback_function' ); 
    remove_submenu_page('pages','pages');   
}
add_action( "admin_menu", "admin_pages_menu" );
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Chris Gatt. How can I add another sub menu ? Thanks.